# Woocommerce - How to program a loop to find sub-categories of a category and display the Category Title and the products in it

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce

Hi I am looking to create category templates in Woocommerce that based on the category they are applicable to it searches to find the child categories of that category and display the heading of the sub-categories with the products in that sub category beneath them.

I have created the category templates and have for the time being hard coded in the shortcodes to display the sub categories and their products, however this does not allow the client to create a new product subcategory and assign products to it without my further intervention, can someone help?

The URL to the site in question and a page that uses the hardcoded shortcodes in the category template is:

http://www.globalleisurefurniture.co.uk/products/tablestopsbases/table-bases/

So essentially I want to be able to create this page using a loop of some kind rather than hardcoded shortcodes...

Any questions feel free to ask and thanks in advance of any help provided!

Answer (score 2):

I've done basically the same thing, but without looping through and showing the products. To get a list of the children for the parent category on my archives page, I added:

```
function woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($parent_cat_id, $current_cat_name = ''){

                               $args = array(
                                  'hierarchical' => 1,
                                  'show_option_none' => '',
                                  'hide_empty' => 0,
                                  'parent' => $parent_cat_id,
                                  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
                               );

                                $subcats = get_categories($args);

                                echo '<ul class="wooc_sclist">';

                              //first link will be "view all for parent cat"
                              $parent_info = get_term_by('id', $parent_cat_id, 'product_cat');
                              $parent_permalink = get_term_link($parent_info, 'product_cat');

                              echo '<li>';
                              echo '<a href="'.$parent_permalink.'">View All ';
                              echo $parent_info->name;
                              echo '</a>';
                              echo '</li>';

                              foreach ($subcats as $sc) {

                                    print_r($sc); // this will give you the sub cat info for each sub category, and you should be able to use the info in the array to build your loop here

                                    $link = get_term_link( $sc->slug, $sc->taxonomy );

                                 echo '<li class="';

                                 if($current_cat_name == $sc->name){
                                    echo 'active ';
                                 } 

                                 echo '" ><a href="'. $link .'">'.$sc->name.'</a></li>';

                              }//foreach

                                echo '</ul>';

                            } //function

                            if($parent_cat_id != 0){
                                woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($parent_cat_id, $current_category);
                            }
                            else{
                                woocommerce_subcats_from_parentcat_by_ID($cur_cat_id, $current_category);
                            }
```

You should be able to use the print_r($sc) that I added above in the code above to get the needed info for that sub category to build your loop.